# Can i upload data via c# to firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Want to make a WPF app that can upload data to my Firestore database (i has to be able to make documents in this collection)
this is what my DB looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otVFa.png
now I was thinking what the best way was, via a nuget extension in Visual studio or via a API in VisualStudio.
Can you help me out?

Comment: Firestore has client libraries for a variety of environments and languages including C#. Visual studio is kind of irrelevant to your question. You may find more information in the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?hl=sl#c

Answer (score 1):

> Can I upload data via c# to Firebase Firebase?

Sure you can. As also @mcy mentioned in his comment, Firebase already provides a C# client library that can help you achieve that. To be able to add a new document to your existing "werken" collection, please use the following lines of code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> doc = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "description", "Lorem ipsum..." },
    { "description_short", "Lorem ipsum..." },
    { "img", "W3.jpg" },
    { "selable", true },
    { "title", "W3" }
};
DocumentReference addedDocRef = await db.Collection("werken").AddAsync(doc);
Console.WriteLine("Added document with ID: {0}.", addedDocRef.Id);
```

As you can see, we let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you by calling `add()`.